# Why does sequelize return 500 [object SequelizeInstance:Users] when connecting to express session?

Tags: node.js, express, session, sequelize.js, passport.js

### The Problem:

I'm trying to authenticate a user with passport-local strategy. I can successfully retrieve the user from the database, but when I try to redirect to ' / ' and initiate a new session, my server responds with 500 [object SequelizeInstance:Users]

### Context:

I came across the 'connect-session-sequelize' node package and implemented it in my app.js:

```
const db = require('./models/db.js');
const userController = require('./controllers/user');
const myStore = new SequelizeStore({
  db: db.sequelize,
  table: 'Sessions'
});

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  store: myStore,
  resave: false, // per the express-session docs this should be set to false
  proxy: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.get('/login', userController.getLogin);
app.post('/login', userController.postLogin);
app.get('/signup', userController.getSignup);
app.post('/signup', userController.postSignup);

db.sequelize.sync({
  force: false,
}).then(() => {
  app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('%s App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode', chalk.green('✓'), app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
  });
});
```

My routes handling the requests:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const db = require('../models/db.js');
const User = db.user;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('serializing user: ', user);
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: { email: email.toLowerCase() },
  }).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { msg: `Email ${email} not found.` });
    }
    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      }
      return done(null, false, { msg: 'Invalid email or password.' });
    });
  });
}));

exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = req.validationErrors();
  const user = new User({
    username: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  User.findOne({
    where: { email: req.body.email }
  }).then((existingUser) => {
    if (existingUser) {
      req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.' });
      return res.redirect('/signup');
    }
    user.save((err) => {
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/'));
      });
    });
  });
};
```

'Users' DB model:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Users = sequelize.define('Users', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password_hash: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: false,
      set(value) {
        const that = this;
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
          if (err) { return console.log('BCRYPT GEN SALT ERR:', err); }

          bcrypt.hash(value, salt, null, (error, hash) => {
            if (error) { return console.log('BCRYPT HASH ERR:', err); }

            console.log('--> SEQ: BCRYPT hash SET', hash);
            that.setDataValue('password', value);
            that.setDataValue('password_hash', hash);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

  Users.prototype.comparePassword = function comparePassword(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password_hash, (err, isMatch) => {
      cb(err, isMatch);
    });
  };
  return Users;
};
```

'Sessions' DB model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => sequelize
  .define('Sessions', {
    sid: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: DataTypes.STRING,
    expires: DataTypes.DATE,
    data: DataTypes.STRING(50000),
  });
```

### Server Response:

> POST /login 302 234.474 ms - 46
>
> Executing (default): SELECT "sid", "userId", "expires", "data", "createdAt",
> "updatedAt" FROM "Sessions" AS "Sessions" WHERE "Sessions"."sid" =
> 'Jhmo9YA9MhwKEVa6zWxvvRQGdYoXmdSQ';
>
> Executing (default): SELECT "id", "username", "email", "password_hash", "phone",
> "age", "gender", "location", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "Users"
>
> WHERE "Users"."id" = 'c40d4cd6-4937-4a66-b785-d302e9fa6c40';
>
> Executing (default): UPDATE "Sessions" SET "expires"='2018-05-10 06:31:42.797
> +00:00',"updatedAt"='2018-05-09 06:31:42.797 +00:00' WHERE "sid" =
> 'Jhmo9YA9MhwKEVa6zWxvvRQGdYoXmdSQ'
>
> [object SequelizeInstance:Users]
> GET / 500 5.420 ms - -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deserializeUser` should call `done` with error first:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('serializing user: ', user.id);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then((user) => {
    done(null, user);
  }).catch(done);
});
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the answer, I thought user deserializing happened on logout, not login though?

Comment: Nope, `deserializeUser` happens when server receive the request and find user by id in the session store. `serializeUser` happens when login or end of request, save the user id into session.